# In Ex Machina, can this character survive?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, science, androids, ex-machina

This is not about

> Caleb

who I'm quite sure is doomed, but

> Ava. In the end she escapes, looks entirely human and is free to roam the city like she always wanted.
>  However, as far as we can tell she can only charge her batteries by using special panels that only existed in Nathan's house. She doesn't seem to have a power cord that she could plug in to a socket and, being entirely mechanical, can't eat food.

Is there any way this character could survive for long?

Comment: I'd actually like to add that I don't think Caleb is doomed - we already know that the doors will all open after the powercut stops (as he programmed them to do), so won't he just leave the facility then?

Comment: @DrRDizzle:   The power cuts were explained to be because Ava was reversing the charging process of her batteries to cause the power system to fault.   Why would you assume this continues after she is gone?

Comment: @DrRDizzle - We see Caleb slumped by the door **after** the power has shorted out. Clearly the hack has reversed itself and the doors are failing safe again. There's no definitive evidence that he died, but I think we can reasonably assume he did.

Comment: I think her intentionally arranging his death is part of what makes the ending interesting anyway.  Him surviving doesn't really do anything good for the film, apart from making us go "yay, he survived!"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In the [original script](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=yvFMBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT122&lpg=PT122&dq=%22Somewhere+we+can+buy+an+induction+plate%22&source=bl&ots=aU6CmZQjiH&sig=tTFMlOckujvAXSFXs2WggvcC600&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-ZhZVYyUH4P9UIX7gZAF&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22Somewhere%20we%20can%20buy%20an%20induction%20plate%22&f=false),  Caleb's plan was to simply take her somewhere that they could purchase a compatible [induction charging plate](http://www.androidcentral.com/these-android-phones-can-handle-wireless-charging), a technology that has presumably become relatively commonplace in the near-future:

> **CALEB:** *How long does your battery charge last?*
>
> **AVA:** *Twenty six hours.*
>
> **CALEB:** *So **we’ll have about a day to get to a cell-phone or kitchen appliance store. Somewhere we can buy an induction plate.**
>   After that...*

Although this line was cut, there seems little reason to assume that the film-makers had anything different in mind.

---

Alex Garland had this to say in a recent [Reddit AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/35brre/i_am_alex_garland_the_writer_and_director_of_ex/), basically confirming the details above;

> Thank you. Re: batteries, I had some idea that she used induction
>   plates to charge (there are a few dotted around her room, which she
>   presses her hand to) and that **in the future of the film, induction
>   plates were more powerful and readily available than they are now...**

Comment: The thing is, how does she expect to buy an induction plate without Caleb?

Answer (score 12):

She is a pretty clever AI.

She worked out that she needed to manipulate Caleb, use Kyoko in her escape, and that she could mess around with her internal systems to cause a black out. I would be surprised if she was incapable of building her own charger somehow.

She has all the knowledge of blue book at her disposal, I'm fairly sure that she could create some way of charging her batteries.

Answer (score 4):

Caleb will most likely die. Keep in mind he told Ava he changed the protocols to trap Nathan in the room. Caleb knew Nathan would be a threat to the both of them should he escape. At the end, Caleb can't even access the computer to revers the security procedures he changed (in another post someone mentioned this is because Ava caused a short disabling the computer). Ava asks him, "Will you stay," and there are a number of posts on here already that discuss what this means; so I won't go into it here.

Ava will most likely need to return to the facility to reproduce; build other robots. Since she can shutdown the power at regular intervals, she most likely has the knowledge to build her own charger when out among the humans as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think the film provides us that information without the need for additional details.  Purely in terms of the director getting his thought across, I would say Ava's survival is part of the point.

What I mean is that there is a part in the beginning where Caleb goes **"If you've created a conscious machine, it's not the history of man."** Then a short pause, and then Caleb shows his hubris: **"That's the history of gods."**

Caleb got it right, right before he got it wrong: it is no longer the history of man.  From Caleb's perspective, being creators of this new life form makes humans gods; from Ava's perspective it simply makes humans obsolete.  In other words, Ava is the initiation of something new.  So yes, the idea is that she will survive.

Comment: Nathan interpreted it as meaning that *he* was a god, for creating new life, but what Caleb actually meant is that AIs will evolve into gods.  `Nathan: ... I'm not a man, I'm a God. ... Caleb: Yeah, but I didn't say that.`

Answer (score 1):

I think the question about power is fairly prosaic. More interesting is how she would survive as a machine among humans. I am sure she plans to rely upon the "kindness of strangers." It is shown she is of superhuman intelligence -- she must have a plan. I would guess she already has control over Nathan's financial resources.

I think a sequel of her among the humans would be fascinating.

Comment: This appears to be (at best) guesswork.